# Закругление прямоугольной картинки

Tags: html, css

Имеется картинка 400x200px. Необходимо ее закруглить, ширина и высота должна быть равна 60px. При этом картинка не должна растягиваться по высоте, в этом случае растягивается(
`<div><img src="1.png"></div>`

```
div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: в каком плане сужаться? при размере картинки относительно div вложенного в него border-radius не должен  быть больше 30 ибо это уже окружность получается

Answer (score 0):

Если `background-image` с `background-size:cover` не хватает и нужен именно `img`, можно сделать так:

```css
div { 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200">
</div>
```

К сожалению, стили будут работать лишь для горизонтальных изображения (вроде 400×200), для вертикальных понадобится поменять местами `auto` и `100%` у `width` и `height`. Не знаю, поправимо ли это.

На всякий случай, вариант с `background-size:cover`:

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url("https://placekitten.com/400/200") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```